# How to efficiently generate random unique series of bits with specific length?

Tags: julia

Let's say I want to generate 3 unique random series of bits with a length of three. The possible output can be:

```
001 or [0, 0, 1]
010 or [0, 1, 0]
111 or [1, 1, 1]

#or

011 or [0, 1, 1]
110 or [1, 1, 0]
111 or [1, 1, 1]

# etc.
```

I provided two notations above (the Vector notation is preferred). The point is where they should be unique. I tried:

```
julia> unique(convert.(BitVector, rand.(Ref([0, 1]), repeat([3], 3))))
2-element Vector{BitVector}:
 [0, 1, 1]
 [0, 1, 0]
```

As you can see, there might be a set of two unique BitVectors rather than 3 and this is natural here. I can replace `repeat([3], 3)` with `repeat([3], 6)` to somewhat ensure I would get three unique sets:

```
julia> unique(convert.(BitVector, rand.(Ref([0, 1]), repeat([3], 5))))[1:3]
3-element Vector{BitVector}:
 [1, 0, 0]
 [1, 1, 1]
 [1, 0, 1]
```

But I wonder if there's any better idea for this?

*However, I'm really curious about how I can efficiently generate the first notation for this question (like `101`, `001`, etc.).

Comment: Aside from the provided answers, I'd like to point out some other issues: `rand([0, 1], n)` uses Int64 and Vector, but it should much rather be Bools and tuples, e.g. `rand((false, true), n)`, or even better, `rand(Bool, n)`. `repeat` should rarely be used, use `fill(3, n)` instead. Avoid creating small vectors in most cases, like `[3]` or `[0, 1]`. Furthermore, converting a random vector to BitVector is unnecessary, when one can directly use `bitrand`.

Comment: @DNF: Thank you so much! Yes, I learned about `rand(Bool, n)` from you in the comments of AboAmmar's answer. Thank you for these excellent points! You said *"Avoid creating small vectors in most cases, like [3] or [0, 1]"*, but you didn't say the proper replacement (I ask this if you mean that as a general rule in most cases!)

Comment: You can use tuples instead for this. Eg. `rand((a, b, c), n)` instead of `rand([a, b, c], n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another nice option is:

```
using Random, StatsBase

function randseqset(N, L)
    L < sizeof(Int)*8-1 || error("Short seqs only")
    m = BitArray(undef, L, N)
    s = sample(0:(1<<L)-1, N; replace=false)
    map(i->digits!(@view(m[:,i]), s[i]; base=2), 1:N)
end
```

A version with simple vectors instead of `@views` is:

```
function randseqset(N, L)
    L < sizeof(Int)*8-1 || error("Short seqs only")
    s = sample(0:(1<<L)-1, N; replace=false)
    map(i->digits!(Vector{Bool}(undef, L),
      s[i]; base=2), 1:N)
end
```

It has the benefit of adapting to parameters a bit (inherited from the no-replace `sample` code). And it is quite performant and allocation thrifty.

For example:

```
julia> N = 10; L = 4;

julia> @btime randSeq($N, $L);
  1.126 μs (16 allocations: 1.12 KiB)

julia> @btime randseqset($N, $L);
  654.878 ns (5 allocations: 944 bytes)
```

PS If `Matrix{Bool}` preferable to `BitMatrix` then replace `m = ...` line with `m = Matrix{Bool}(undef, L, N)`

PPS As for the question about the strings, the following works (using same logic as above):

```
randseqstrset(N, L) = getindex.(
  bitstring.(sample(0:(1<<L)-1, N; replace=false)),
  Ref(sizeof(Int)*8-L+1:sizeof(Int)*8))
```

for example:

```
julia> randseqstrset(3,3)
3-element Vector{String}:
 "101"
 "000"
 "011"
```

UPDATE: If speed is really an issue, another version can use some BitMatrix trickery:

```
function randBitSeq2(N, L)
    BM = BitMatrix(undef, 0,0)
    BM.chunks = sample(0:2^L-1, N; replace=false)
    BM.dims = (sizeof(Int64)*8, N)
    BM.len = sizeof(Int64)*8*N
    return @view(BM[1:L,:])
end
```

This version is called `randBitSeq2` because it returns a matrix like `randBitSeq` but is twice as fast:

```
julia> @btime randBitSeq2(50,10);
  1.882 μs (5 allocations: 9.20 KiB)

julia> @btime randBitSeq(50,10);
  3.634 μs (3 allocations: 9.17 KiB)
```

Comment: Thanks, your method returns an object of complicated type: `Vector{SubArray{Bool, 1, BitMatrix, Tuple{Slice{OneTo{Int64}}, Int64}, true}}`. But the one that AboAmmar suggested returns a `Set{Vector{Bool}}`. So I don't find your comparison a fair one.

Comment: The type is not essential for comparison result. You are welcome to drop the preallocation and use `digits!(Vector{Bool}(undef, L), s[i]; base=2)`, it won't change the result substantially (specifically: `899.680 ns` vs. `1.289 μs` with same allocation)

Comment: Furthermore, if you can also try to compare with `N = 5; L = 2`. `randSeq` will **not terminate** while the function defined here will raise an exception. In any case, it is also a matter of taste which method fits better.

Comment: Using `digits!(Vector{Bool}(undef, L), s[i]; base=2)` is somewhat similar to my expected output object. But the comparison isn't valid to me. I can compare two ways if and only if they lead to the **same object**. The reason behind accepting this answer is mostly where you proposed dropping the preallocation and noted the drawback of the `randSeq`. And Thanks for the method you've provided for accomplishing the first notation (However, I don't want it in a string. I was wondering if we can make bit objects like `001`). Thanks at all. 

Comment: Thanks for the update! I learned new things, and the latter approach is so elegant.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** The following `randBitSeq` will be 3X faster. It generates unique random numbers first, then it fills a `Bool`ean matrix with their binary values.

```
using StatsBase

function randBitSeq(N, L)
    M = Matrix{Bool}(undef,N,L)
    S = sample(0:2^L-1, N; replace=false)
    i = 0
    for n in S
        i += 1
        for j = 1:L
            if n > 0
                M[i,j] = isodd(n)
                n ÷= 2
            else
                M[i,j] = false
            end
        end
    end
    return M
end

@btime randBitSeq(50, 10)
1.350 μs (3 allocations: 9.17 KiB)
# vs.
@btime randseqset(50, 10)
3.050 μs (5 allocations: 10.84 KiB)
```

---

Constructing all possible combinations will exponentially eat memory. A better option is to generate a `Set` of `N` random binary series of length `L` each. Then add more series if the required number is not achieved. This seems much faster for `N,L > 3`.

```
function randSeq(N, L)
    s = Set(rand(Bool,L) for i=1:N)
    while length(s) < N
        push!(s, rand(Bool,L))
    end 
    s
end

N = 50;  L = 10
@btime randSeq($N, $L)
 4.071 μs (57 allocations: 4.71 KiB)
```

Comment: `rand((true, false), L)` should rather be `rand(Bool, L)`. But preferably, one should probably use `Random.bitrand(L)`.

Comment: Yes, `rand(Bool, L)` is nice, but `bitrand(L)` will be slightly slower.

Comment: Do you mean the `push!` part? Because `bitrand` itself should be dramatically *faster* than `rand`.

Comment: See another version at the other answer. It is 2X faster than `randBitSeq`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought: given you're only talking about bit strings of length 3, instead of trying to randomly generate them and then enforce uniqueness, how about just take the set of all 3 bit strings and shuffle it around, and then select 3.

For example you could use `collect(Iterators.product([0,1],[0,1],[0,1]))` to generates all length 3 bit strings, and then `shuffle(x)[1:3]` from `Random` to sample without replacement, e.g.

```
julia> using Random

julia> shuffle(collect(Iterators.product([0,1],[0,1],[0,1])))[1:3]
3-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},1}:
 (0, 1, 1)
 (1, 1, 1)
 (1, 0, 1)
```

Also if you want `BitVector`s instead you can do

```
julia> shuffle(BitArray.(Iterators.product([0,1],[0,1],[0,1])))[1:3]
3-element Array{BitArray{1},1}:
 [1, 0, 1]
 [0, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 1]
```

Obviously this won't scale well with the length of the strings, but a suggestion for this small case.

Comment: Nice. But I doubt if it's efficient in lengthy samples (say 50) since it's `collect`ing all possible combinations. However, I didn't mention anything about strings and they aren't in my concern here (if you search, you'll find no words like the “string” in the question).

Comment: Oh yea it would be incredibly awful for that lol. For that setting it isn't obvious how to do anything better than roughly what you're already mentioning: sampling with replacement, checking uniqueness, and then resampling as necessary.